# How can I center text inside TLFTextField when using custom fonts?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

As per title, how can I do it? Here is a minimal working example which reflects my scenario:

```
import fl.text.TLFTextField;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.*;
import flashx.textLayout.elements.TextFlow;
import flashx.textLayout.edit.*;

var tf:TLFTextField = new TLFTextField();
tf.embedFonts = true;
tf.text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean suscipit semper viverra.';
var format:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
format.fontFamily = 'MyPlainFont';
format.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF;    
format.fontSize = 14;
format.textAlign = TextAlign.CENTER;

var editManager:EditManager = new EditManager();
var sel:SelectionState = new SelectionState(tf.textFlow, 0, 86);
tf.textFlow.interactionManager = editManager;
editManager.applyLeafFormat(format, sel);

var format2:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
format2.fontFamily = 'MyBoldFont';
format2.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF;
format2.fontSize = 14;
format2.textAlign = TextAlign.CENTER;
var sel2:SelectionState = new SelectionState(tf.textFlow, 0, 20);
editManager.applyLeafFormat(format2, sel2);

tf.width = 100;
tf.wordWrap = true;

addChild(tf);
```

Comment: i would not use TLFTextField, it has problems.

Answer (score 0):

For normal TextFields you have to asign the format before you add the text otherwise it doesnt apply, have tried that?

Comment: Yes, that way it centers, but it won't apply the fonts properly, it will use only the last font applied.

Answer (score 0):

This code below will fix your problem. It's like Sidrich said, **always set the text property at last! I also added the autoSize property, bacause if not setting this, I've seen some strange positioning glitches.**

```
import fl.text.TLFTextField;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.TextLayoutFormat;
import flashx.textLayout.edit.EditManager;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.TextAlign;
import flashx.textLayout.edit.SelectionState;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

var tf:TLFTextField = new TLFTextField();
tf.embedFonts = true;
tf.border = true;

var format:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
format.fontFamily = 'MyPlainFont';
format.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF;    
format.fontSize = 14;
format.textAlign = TextAlign.CENTER;
var editManager:EditManager = new EditManager();
var sel:SelectionState = new SelectionState(tf.textFlow, 0, 86);
tf.textFlow.interactionManager = editManager;
editManager.applyLeafFormat(format, sel);

var format2:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
format2.fontFamily = 'MyBoldFont';
format2.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF;
format2.fontSize = 14;
format2.textAlign = TextAlign.CENTER;
var sel2:SelectionState = new SelectionState(tf.textFlow, 0, 20);
editManager.applyLeafFormat(format2, sel2);

tf.width = 100;
tf.wordWrap = true;
tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
tf.text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean suscipit semper viverra.';

addChild(tf);
```

Comment: By adding the text at last it will center, but won't apply the custom fonts on text, it will use only the last font applied.

Comment: About embedding fonts, you could read [this](http://marumushi.com/news/embedding-fonts-in-as3) link.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem I have implemented 
http://flashthusiast.com/2010/05/05/getting-started-with-the-tlftextfield-class-in-actionscript-3-0-and-flash-cs5/comment-page-1/#comment-72699

and just added `textAlign='center'` to paragraph tag to get in center.

It belongs to text formats for tlf flashx text-formats

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/formats/TextAlign.html#CENTER